# Rename column with same column name based on values in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which can contain columns with the same column name. Based on the value I want to rename the column name so there are no duplicates. I've tried a few things, but every time I try to iterate over the columns and rename them I end up with the column name. df.rename(columns=df.columns[i]: 'some_name'}) seems to use the column name as well.

Let's say I have a dataframe;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10kg], "B": [4], "A": [4%]})
```

I would like to rename the column(s) named "A" based on the row value so that I get

```
   A     B  A%
0  10kg  4  4
```

I tried something like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    if 'A' in df.columns[i]:
        if '%' in df.iloc[:,i].values[0]:
            df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[i]: 'A_%'})
```

But this also renames the first column 'A'. Is there another way to rename it based on location?

Comment: how did you create a df with 2 same columns?

Comment: what do you mean by row value?

Comment: @anky_91 probably pd.concat(..., axis=1) or loading from a file

Comment: @mcsoini it is not a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  then :)

Comment: @anky_91 I see very few of those on stackoverflow :(

Comment: it was a result of scraping a site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single list comprehension for new column names:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({"A": ['10kg'], "B": ['4']}), 
                pd.DataFrame({"A": ['4%']})], axis=1)


df.columns = [c + '_%'
              if df.applymap(lambda x: '%' in x).any(axis=0).iloc[ic]
              else c for ic, c in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

Edit -- better:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({"A": ['10kg'], "B": ['4']}), 
                pd.DataFrame({"A": ['4%']})], axis=1)

has_percentage = df.applymap(lambda x: '%' in x).any(axis=0)
df.columns = [c + '_%' if has_percentage.iloc[ic]
              else c for ic, c in enumerate(df.columns)]
```

Comment: awesome, very nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list with all the column names, change the i'th column name in that list and use that list to redefine the column names:

```
for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    if 'A' in df.columns[i]:
        if '%' in df.iloc[:,i].values[0]:
            columnnames = list(df.columns)
            columnnames[i] = 'A_%'
            df.columns = columnnames
```