# Naming dataframe columns based on the content of one of the row indices

Tags: python, dataframe, multiple-columns, rename, spyder

Here is my data frame after reading the csv file and splitting it into columns.

```
Index         0                  1         2

0   Dylos Logger v 1.6.0.0      None      None
1   Unit: DC1700 v 2.08         None      None

2   Date/Time: 12-07-15 11:11   None      None

3   -------------------------   None      None

4   Particles per cubic foot    None      None

5   -------------------------   None      None

6   Date/Time                   Small     Large

7   11-27-15 10:08              161200    8300

8   11-27-15 10:09              136500    8700

9   11-27-15 10:10              124000    8400
 
10  11-27-15 10:11              127300    7900
```

I would like to name my columns based on the content in the 6th row index, then get rid of the first 6 indices, and reset the index from zero. This means that I wish my data to look like this:

```
0   Date/Time                  Small     Large

1   11-27-15 10:08             161200    8300

2   11-27-15 10:09             136500    8700

3   11-27-15 10:10             124000    8400

4   11-27-15 10:11             127300    7900
```

I know how to remove the first 6 rows and rest the indices. But I do not know how to rename the column name based on row 6 at the first step. Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58861560/rename-column-with-same-column-name-based-on-values-in-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'0':['a','Date/Time','x'],'1':['b','Small','y'],'2':['c','Large','z']})
row_with_column_names = 1 #would be 6 for you
df = df.rename(columns={cur_name:new_name for cur_name,new_name in zip(df,df.iloc[row_with_column_names,:])}) #rename
df = df.drop(row_with_column_names,axis='index') #remove the row with the names in it
df = df.reset_index(drop=True) 
df

#Produces
#   Date/Time   Small   Large
#0  a   b   c
#1  x   y   z
```